# Build.prop modifies okay. But not updates in system (e.g. About Tablet in settings)

Tags: root-access, file-system, file-permissions, compatibility, file-properties

I am running Android-x86 4.4 on VirtualBox. Everything works fine. 
But when I am modifying build.prop (with ES File Explorer or BuildProp Editor) with other manufacturer or model and save it. After reboot nothing happens. In About Tablet stores the old information.

Seems that android cache this info somewhere.

Any thoughts? How to force Android to update from build.prop

Comment: I've found that info about manufacturer, model (and other) Android takes not from build.prop, it uses /sys/class/dmi/id/, but I can't change anything in these files

Comment: Another interesting thing  that in Android 4.0 changing build.prop make effect and everything works fine.

Comment: I am having the same issue.. I am curios, you found a way to modify that info on the 4.4?

Comment: Yes, I use Build Prop editor https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.build.prop.editor&hl=en and it works

Answer (score -1):

I found that there are a lot of other build.prop, ex: build.(...).prop
I deleted all except the last one and it works.